# I want to Display Wordpress Blog Post in my Bootstrap Website

Tags: html, wordpress, bootstrap-4

i want to display the 3 latest post from my wordpress blog (www.xyz.wordpress.com) in my bootstrap html website. I don't want to use PHP to do that.

I came close by using feedburner, but im limited in the CSS styles(i also dont want the "Headline by Feedburner" thing). I want the post to be in blocks (3 column) and with an the image and title from the wordpress blog.

The idea is instead of changing the HTML codes on my website, i just have to update my wordpress blog posts and that should update my website as well.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the blog feed from https://xyz.wordpress.com/feed/ and then read it from a JavaScript script:

https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/rss-reader-in-javascript/